# How to make div container the full height of the screen?

Tags: html, css

Ok so I am making my first iOS HTML5 app and it is just a simple quote app.  I need to figure out how to make my container div be the full height of the iphone.  Here is a jsfiddle of my design - http://jsfiddle.net/gKaDL/1/

```
.container {
width: 640px;
min-height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
```

Because a lot of the quotes are short the container div will not reach the iPhone 4 screen height of 960px let alone the iPhone 5's 1136px height.  The container div must be the size of the screen or larger as there is a background image on it that must fill the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have either the CSS unit `vh` that is in centieth of viewport height. In which case you would write:

```
height: 100vh;
```

Or you can force the div to stick to top and bottom of the closest positioned parent (so give `position:relative` or `position: absolute` to a parent that has the appropriate height):

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

tell me if you need more details

Comment: `vh` isn't dynamic though: it triggers once and when you resize the screen, it doesn't resize with.

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
margin:0px auto;
width:100%;
height:100%;

}
```